# How to uninstall VS2008 hotfix KB971092 and KB2465361

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I remove microsoft visual stuido 2008 and upgrade to 2010, I notice two hotfix updates cannot be uninstalled from Program and Features.

They showed up in my Windows 7 Installed Updates list as

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2465361)
Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB971092)

When i click uninstall, it will tell me "This action is only valid for products that are currently installed".

I have tried different install clean up utilities but still cannot get rid of them. Is there a way to manually remove these updates?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't remove them, they are security patches for the C++ runtime support libraries.  They are not just used by the programs you create with Visual Studio, other programs installed on your machine use those DLLs as well.  Forcibly removing the patch will break those other programs.  I'm guessing you get the error because KB2465361 supersedes KB971092.

There's also little reason to uninstall VS2008, it doesn't get in the way of VS2010.  Some VS2010 projects still use the build tools that came with VS2008.  Targeting .NET 3.5 and earlier in C++/CLI projects requires the VS2008 tool chain.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response. I only want to remove VS2008 because I need disk space on my system drive. I will leave those hot fix there for now.